# Windows Disabling System Shortcut of another layout

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, windows-11

I'm running Windows 10 and 11 on my laptops (the issue is applicable to both) and have English and Russian keyboard layouts. I have a laptop monitor and an external monitor connected via USB-C.

When I'm using Russian Layout, Sometimes I Accidentally type Alt + F8 for my Java Development IDE (IntelliJ).
Once I do it, the two monitors setup stops working and it switch to showing my stuff only on one monitor, then I have to re-apply the "extend-view on two monitors" via Display Settings.
When I'm using English Keyboard Layout it never happens.

So my question is whether I can somehow disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will disable
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>
in Windows entirely:

```
!F8::
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: AutoHotkey sounds good, however I'm not sure I can install it on the corporate PC which I use for Work... Is there any Windows internal utility that can manage/alter hotkeys assignments ?

Comment: There is a portable version available [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/) - download the ZIP version (I recommend V1).